# AWS EC2 Security Groups

Tags: ubuntu, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hello and apologies if this is the wrong stackexchange forum,

I am setting up an AWS EC2 instance of Ubuntu 14.04 for R Shiny apps based on this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-aws/

I would like the apps to only be accessible in my home so when I setup the Security Groups I set the source for inbound, and outbound (should I set both?) to be my specific IP address. If I understand correctly, this should make it impossible to access the instance from a different IP address (i.e outside my home).

I also found this post that describes how to set up a firewall, and connect with HTTPS: http://ipub.com/shiny-https/

Does it make sense to use both security mechanisms? How effective would these mechanisms be in preventing a third-party from accessing my instance?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question. Then you won't have to say "apologies if this is the wrong stackexchange forum"

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: How does this not fall under: "personal and home computer networking"?

Comment: Read the tag. Webapps are off-topic,

Comment: @DavidPostill Please see https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11991/where-do-ec2-and-aws-questions-truly-belong.  Please don't send these to WA in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense to use both Security Groups and HTTPS. Security Groups can only filter traffic once a request is inside AWS infrastructure, while HTTPS protects against capturing your data and man-in-the-middle attacks while your traffic is in transit in open internet.

No, generally you should not restrict outbound traffic to you home IP. Your EC2 instance should be able to connect to other internet resources, for example, `yum` or `apt` repositories for software updates.